# Is there a way of automatically suspending processes that are running in unfocused workspaces?

Tags: workspaces, process

Is there a task manager (or an option) that can automatically suspend processes (or slow them down)  in unused workspaces?

For example I have Chromium in one workspace and it takes quite a lot of CPU power because I have a lot of tags. I want to do something else in another workspace and I don't want Chromium to slow me down. How can I suspend it automatically?

Comment: I think you mean *workspace* when you call it desktop, right?

Comment: you mean selecting different _process_ for different _workspaces_?

Comment: yes i mean workspace
maybe there is a way of putting less priority for these processes

Answer (score 0):

No one seems to have answered your question so i will give you at least a bit of what you are asking for.

I don't believe there is really any way of suspending it automatically depending on what work space it is on. Or that it always be a good idea. What if you are streaming music or downloading a file? The TCP connection will hang and the server drop it after a while.

There are commands you can use that might get you in the right direction of "semi-automation"

running the command:

```
kill -STOP pidOfProgram
```

will background / stop the process.

```
kill -CONT pidOfProgram
```

will foreground / return it to its previous state

Pids change though. If you want to use it in a script (so you can bind it to a key combination for example)
you could try using use this:

```
kill -STOP `pgrep -o chrome`
```

to background
    kill -CONT `pidof -o chrome`
to resume

Comment: Why no `killall`?